# Is it possible to recreate only specific versions with carrierwave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use carrierwave and I store the original image plus 3 (lets call them `thumbnail`, `crop_small` and `crop_big`) other versions. `thumbnail` has the same ratio, but is smaller in size and the other ones are cropped. The copped versions have the same image part and differ in size.

After cropping (I get x,y,width and height from the frontend) I want only to recreate the cropped versions with the new information, as the thumbnail does not change.

Is this possible in carrierwave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you can pass an argument to recreate_versions! to specify which versions to recreate.

> You might come to a situation where you want to retroactively change a version or add a new one. You can use the recreate_versions! method to recreate the versions from the base file. This uses a naive approach which will re-upload and process the specified version or all versions, if none is passed as an argument.

I had the same question actually, because I thought you couldn't do this, but it turns out you can.